# How to stop google docs replacing parentheses?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to make google docs stop replacing parentheses?
Sometimes I make there cheat sheets for myself but I noticed that when I make parentheses there it places [image] instead of [image] which do not work in a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called smart quotes.

To turn them off, click `Tools > Preferences` and then unselect `Use smart quotes`:

[image]